# Fixed width in table

Tags: html

How can I fix the width of column in a table and make it be at a given width and not stretch with its content?

I have to say that I put `width="300px"` for example in `<td>` tag but not changes happen.

Comment: i found the problem that cause width property does not work. it was {strip} code in smarty tpl file.i removed it and the width is fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
<td width="300"></td>
```

or

```
<td style="width:300px"></td>
```

or

```
<td class="fixedCell"></td>
```

and

```
.fixedCell { width:300px; } /* In a CSS file. */
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `with="300px"`  to `width="300"` and also table width should be more than the width of cell

Comment: sorry i mean width not with,that was a mistype issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using explicit column sizing with `colgroup` usually works for me.

I have prepared a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aBC4R/).